# How to translate "Products Comparison List - Magento commerce"

Tags: page-title, inline-translations

I managed to translate **"Products Comparison List"** but the following line **"- Magento commerce"** I'm not able to translate. Can't figure it out. I tried with the **Mage_Catalog.csv** file and **catalog.xml** but could find the translation for  "- Magento commerce".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant translate it via csv.
In admin:
System->Configuration.

In General tab Click on Design.

Find "HTML HEAD" and replace "Magento commerce"  in Default Title field.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hi, I think you are not able to translate this line of text with inline translation, becouse this text is in <title>Products Comparison List - Magento commerce</title> tag.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for replay. I think there is no HTML Head field in my version of mangeto which is 1.9.2

Comment: There is. I added a screenshot to the answer.

Comment: Thank you all. You were right. That was the way to translate this. I have been missing head html function in magento. This trick worked. Please visit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909156/magento-html-head-dropdown-missing